# Alternatives to getReference method in Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I found myself struggling to implement customizable methods in Spring Data JPA.
For example, I have a Pet class, which has an Owner(Many to One rel.) What if I have a method to `save(Pet pet, int ownerId)`. How can I get `ownerId`? Using Hibernate I just can `getReference` like that

```
public Pet save(Pet pet, int ownerId) {
        if (!pet.isNew() && get(pet.getId(), ownerId) == null) {
            return null;
        }
        pet.setUser(em.getReference(Owner.class, ownerId));
        if (pet.isNew()) {
            em.persist(pet);
            return pet;
        } else {
            return em.merge(pet);
        }
    }
```

But using a Spring DJPA it's not so easy. I've created an interface that extends `JpaRepository < Pet, Integer >`, hoping that the parent class has a method called 
`saveWithReference`, but i didn't find anything.. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Assuming you also have a `OwnerRepository` use the `getOne` method... Which returns a reference. (All of this is also explained in the javadoc of the [`JpaRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-).

Comment: So, should I have OwnerRepository also in PetRepository?

Comment: You should have an `OwnerRepository`.

Comment: I've already created it, and implemented all the CRUD methods just as they in JpaRepo. It's much harder to implement PetRepository, since there's reference to ownerID, not simple crud

Comment: Why would you need to implement it?! You shouldn't implement those interfaces, Spring Data creates implementations for you. You should have a service which has a method which stores the Pet and contains the logic delegating to the needed repositories. Basically what you posted here using an `EntityManager` should be in a service and instead of an `EntityManager` it should be using the repositories.

Comment: I mean in OwnerRepository I just delegated all the methods to SimpleJpaRepository

Comment: I still don't get it ... You don't need to implement anything. As stated just implement the code you wrote in your post and instead of `em.getReference`. do `ownderRepository.getOne(ownerId)`. You are making things to complex.

Comment: Well, sorry for my unclear explanation
Ok then, I'll have 2 interfaces, which extend JpaRepository<Owner, Integer> and JpaRepository<Pet, Integer> accordingly. In CrudOwnerRepo I just override methods, that are in JpaRepository. Then, I have DataJpaOwnerImp that implements just OwnerRepo where I have my interface CrudOwnerRepo and do my CRUD operations via it. The problem is how to make it in DateJpaPetImp where I need to refer to the userId. Hope it's clear.

Comment: You still don't get it. You don't implement the interfaces. Spring Data implements them for you. Instead of doing the wrong things, I suggest a read of the Spring Data JPA guide... Also you should write a service not implement that logic in a repository.

Answer (score 29):

You should have both a `PetRepository` and `OwnerRepository` both extending `JpaRepository`.

```
public interface PetRepository extends JpaRepository<Pet, Long> {}
```

and

```
public interface OwnerRepository extends JpaRepository<Owner, Long> {}
```

Using Spring Data JPA you can use the [`getOne`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-) method to get a reference, this in contrast to the `findOne` which will actually query the database.

The code you wrote using the `EntityManager` is basically the same and you should put that in a service method and instead of directly using the `EntityManager` use the 2 repositories.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public PetService {

    private final PetRepository pets;
    private final OwnerRepository owners;

    public PetService(PetRepository pets, OwnerRepository owners) {
        this.pets=pets;
        this.owners=owners;
    }

    public Pet savePet(Pet pet, long ownerId) {
        if (!pet.isNew() && get(pet.getId(), ownerId) == null) {
            return null;
        }
        pet.setUser(owners.getOne(ownerId));
        return pets.save(pet);
    }
}
```

Something like that should do the trick. NO need to implement methods in your repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day :D

Comment: I tried it and working perfectly. Its alternative to hibernate load method in spring data

Comment: I think it is important to add (cause at least I did not catch it at first) that you can use `get` in a specific query as `find`. e.g - instead of `findById` `getById`. Of course, you'll need to add the signature to the repository as in `find`.